# primefaces 4.0 selectonemenu not displaying dropdown

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

i have a selectonemenu , but it not displaying selection values (not dropdown) i tried it on new page it works fine and i also tried on dialog it is working fine too. maybe it depends on parent CSS but i tried remove them so nothing changed.

```
<h:form>
         <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel id="blg" value="group"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="qGroup" value="#{qstnGroup.selectedGrp}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{qstnGroup.lstGrp}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column><p:outputLabel value="Type"/></p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="qType" value="#{qstnGroup.selectedType}"
                                          required="true">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{qstnGroup.lstType}"/>
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                 ....
         </p:panelgrid>
  </h:form>
```

Comment: Please post your managedbean.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9615921  My ManagedBean

Comment: I think your managedBean is correct. Can you show all of your xhtml?

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/2hrb3pm72ftrptqypppisq

Comment: i found a bug. when i connect with managed bean, form not working perfectly. i think it depends on <h:form> with ManagedBean. when i remove connection with managedbean, every tags working fine(<p:dialog>, <p:selectonemenu>,...)

Comment: Have you try to change <form action="#"> to <h:form action="#"> ?

Comment: yes tried it also not working